# Keyboard app for iOS optimized for latex?

Tags: keyboard

I’m looking for a keyboard I can install for the touchscreen on iOS which is well-suited for typing latex. For example, the backslash and dollar signs should be more easily accessible than on a standard keyboard. Maybe also the caret, underscore, and a few others. Are there good options available?

I’m not looking for anything fancy like handwriting recognition, nor am I looking for a symbol editor. I just want to be able to type latex on the touchscreen without having to switch keyboard modes every time I need a backslash. The sort of thing I’m looking for is simple enough that I’d imagine I could get it for free.

Comment: That's probably hard to find. Instead you can remap your keys. Thre certainly are many apps for that, some listed here: https://etechshout.com/key-mapping-apps-for-ios/

Comment: I've never managed to find one. The basic iOS keyboard is seriously impractical for entering most code of any sort.  Looking through the App store though, there's an app called Keybuild which allows you to create custom keyboards and seems to get good reviews.

Comment: For android, there is the wonderful Hacker's Keyboard https://github.com/klausw/hackerskeyboard which is still available via fdroid and work on current android.